# Do custom events fired on the Tridion UI also get triggered when we use Tridion Core Services?

Tags: 2011, event-system

We have a custom event fired on Component Save when the `Tridion UI` is used. We have another application running as a `Windows Service` which creates and saves components using `Tridion Core Services`.

Does anyone know whether our custom event for the `Tridion UI` is fired when we use `Core Services` to save the component or we should add the custom event logic to the Windows Service?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The events are always fired by the CM kernel (or Publisher in some cases), which means that they are independent from the client.

So, yes, all events will be triggered by your Core Service application.

Comment: Do you know in which cases CM Kernel fires the events and in which does Publisher?

Comment: All publishing-related events are triggered by the Publisher. The namespace of your TcmEventArgs object should give you a decent clue about this. If you look under `Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events` you'll see all the available `TcmEventArgs` members. Those that contain the `Publish` word in their name are likely to be fired by the publisher. Some object types, like `PublishTransaction` are usually updated by the publisher process as well, etc. From an implementation point of view which process fires the event shouldn't make a difference to be honest (unless you want to debug)

Comment: Save events are also fired when a change is made through WebDAV for example.

Comment: The CM event system can be hosted in several processes, because in general the CM Kernel can be hosted in several processes, depending on how it is being used. There is a topic in LiveContent SDL Tridion doc trying to explain this: search for "host debugging" and you should find a topic named "Host processes to use when debugging".

Comment: But are events local to the instance of the CM kernel? To my knowledge events are triggered only on the same machine that hosts the CM kernel (so onSave events are not triggered on the publisher box even though it runs it's own CM kernel).
This would mean that if you have outscaled your CM solution you might run into issues with your events not being triggered on every box... In essence you would have to deploy your event system to EVERY box that runs a CM kernel...

Comment: Yes, events will be fired only on the instance where they occur, and you should deploy your event assembly to every machine that may fire the event you want to implement.